# How to select non-zero columns in a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have data with following format:

```
C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  2  3  4  5  6  0  0
0  1  4  5  6  7  8  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to select non-zero columns, such that column `C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6` in python. Any command that can directly give me desired format.

Comment: What kind of data structure is this?

Comment: Matrix with columns C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6

Comment: @RayyanKhan What kind of matrix? Pandas DF, NumPy array, Python list of lists... etc.

Comment: @ Tomothy32, I have NumPy array of n*n format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `any` along with `numpy` indexing to select columns with non-zero values.

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

---

```
a[:, a.any(0)]
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Also If I want to exclude rows in a similar way, like if I want rows 2 & 3, what command should I use?

Comment: Rows would be `a[a.any(1)]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a library like pandas then it is way more simpler

You just take mean of each column and if they are greater than 0 they are your required columns

For that I will give you a piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("File Path")
a = df.mean(axis=0) #gives you column wise mean
for i in len(a):
   if a[i] > 0:
      print(i)  # i will be your column
```

Comment: since the arrays are of larger size i dont think with loop it would be a good idea to get the desired result as it would require large computation time.

Comment: That array is of size no_of_columns

Comment: @RayyanKhan .any() seems the only other method, but that too uses loops

Comment: Yes but to get you understand I used this method

Comment: If this helped you please make it as verified answer

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,2,3,4,5,6,0,0],
              [0,1,4,5,6,7,8,0,0],
              [0,1,4,5,6,7,8,0,0]])

r = np.nonzero(np.any(a != 0, axis=0))[0]

>>> r
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

If you need those as column names (`C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `C4`, `C5`, `C6`), use `pandas`:

```
columns = ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8']
s = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=columns).any()

s = s[s == 1]

>>> s
C1    True
C2    True
C3    True
C4    True
C5    True
C6    True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your matrix is implemented as a list of lists, where the first index is the column, the second index is the row:

```
matrix[3][2] == 3
```

Then you can use a list comprehension to get a list of only the columns in `matrix` that are not all zeroes

```
nonzero_columns = [column for column in matrix if any(column)]
# any() will return true here if any element of column is nonzero
```